# IBM ILOG CPLEX REST API

Tags: cplex, ilog

I have a web application written in PHP for scheduling, how to use CPLEX CP with web application, for optimizing schedules in web application is there any API or if CP can be integrated as web API using nginx or any other means ?

Thank You
Suds

Answer (score 0):

Within IBM watsonx you can call CPLEX in the cloud with a REST API

https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/DO/wml_cpd_home.html?context=cpdaas

You have many APIs for CPLEX CPOptimizer  (C++, Java, python , dotnet ) and you can embed that to get a web API

And you could also use IBM DOC Optimization Server

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8HWM1igrIg&list=PLLup3HtPKiKr7ZRzGxxV80ZL3-h6UlmiP&index=12